# Convert string to color for objects

Tags: c#, colors, converters

I am wondering how to convert string to a colour I have already set in c#? I have a class which sets a colour from a list and the colour variable name is set as a string. I have objects set as the colour but I am wondering how to set the colours using a colour converter for other objects, I realise this description is poor so hopefully my image will help explain more. Also hopefully someone can help me :)

Image 1 is my current output

**Image 1**
[image]

I want the colours under the "Zone legend" to be the same as the "Sequence Stratigraphy"

My Code for the colour setting of the sequence straigraphy  is below along with my code for the zone legend

**Sequence Stratigraphy Colours**

```
internal static class ZoneColorizer
{
    public static void Colorize(ZoneDto[] zones)
    {
        Color[] colorsToChooseFrom = new Color[] { Colors.DarkSlateGray, Colors.DarkBlue, Colors.DarkRed, Colors.DarkCyan, Colors.DarkGoldenrod, Colors.DarkGreen, Colors.DarkMagenta };
        byte colorIndex = 0;
        foreach (var zone in zones)
        {
            var color = colorsToChooseFrom[colorIndex];
            var zoneColor = Color.FromArgb(128, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            zone.ColourCode = zoneColor.ToString();
            colorIndex++;

            byte subzoneNumber = 50;
            byte totalSubZones = (byte)zone.Subzones.LongLength;

            byte multipler = (byte)(200 / totalSubZones);
            foreach (var subzone in zone.Subzones)
            {
                var subZoneColor = Color.FromArgb(subzoneNumber, color.R, color.G, color.B);
                subzone.ColourCode = subZoneColor.ToString();
                subzoneNumber+= multipler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Zone Legend code**

```
private List<Color> colours;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Zones { get; set; }

    public LegendControl()
    {
        colours = new List<Color>() { Colors.DarkSlateGray, Colors.DarkBlue, Colors.DarkRed, Colors.DarkCyan, Colors.DarkGoldenrod, Colors.DarkGreen, Colors.DarkMagenta };

        InitializeComponent();
        Zones = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        DataContext = Zones;
    }

    public void Bind(ZoneDto[] zones)
    {
        int zoneNumber = 0;
        int rowNumber = 0;

        byte subzoneNumber = 0;
        byte totalsubZones = 0;
        Zones.Clear();
        foreach (var zone in zones)
       {
            Color zoneColor = GetColour(zoneNumber);
            var zonerectangle = CreateZoneRectangle(zone, rowNumber, zoneColor);
            Grid1.Children.Add(zonerectangle);
            var zoneName = CreateZoneName(zone, rowNumber);
            Grid1.Children.Add(zoneName);
            zoneNumber++;
            foreach (var subzone in zone.Subzones)
            {
                totalsubZones++;
                Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                Color subzoneColor = GetGradeColour(subzoneNumber, totalsubZones, zoneColor);
                var subzoneRectangle = CreateSubZoneRectangle(subzone, rowNumber, subzoneColor);
                Grid1.Children.Add(subzoneRectangle);
                var subzoneName = CreateSubZoneName(subzone, rowNumber);
                Grid1.Children.Add(subzoneName);
                subzoneNumber++;
                rowNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    private Rectangle CreateZoneRectangle(ZoneDto zone, int rowNumber, Color zoneColour)
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(zoneColour),
            Margin = new Thickness(2)
        };
        int rowSpan = 0;
        foreach (var subzone in zone.Subzones)
        {
            rowSpan++;
        }
        rectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
        rectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        rectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, rowSpan);
        return rectangle;
    }

    private TextBlock CreateZoneName(ZoneDto zone, int rowNumber)
    {
        Zones.Clear();
        var textblock = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = zone.Name,  
            RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(270),
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        int rowSpan = 0;
        foreach (var subzon in zone.Subzones)
        {
            rowSpan++;
        }
        textblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
        textblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        textblock.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, rowSpan);
        return textblock;
    }

    private Rectangle CreateSubZoneRectangle(ZoneDto subzone, int rowNumber, Color subzoneColor)
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(subzoneColor),
            Margin = new Thickness(2)
        };
        rectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
        rectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        return rectangle;
    }

    private TextBlock CreateSubZoneName(ZoneDto subzone, int rowNumber)
    {
        var textblock = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = subzone.Name,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        textblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
        textblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        return textblock;
    }

    private Color GetColour(int zoneNumber)
    {
        var numOfColours = colours.Count;

        if (zoneNumber >= numOfColours)
        {
            return colours[zoneNumber % numOfColours];
        }
        return colours[zoneNumber];
    }


    private Color GetGradeColour(byte subzoneNumber, byte totalsubZones, Color zoneColour)
    {
        byte multipler = (byte)(200 / totalsubZones);

        byte a = (byte)((subzoneNumber + 1) * multipler);

        return Color.FromArgb(a, zoneColour.R, zoneColour.G, zoneColour.B);
    }
```

**the code for the ZoneDto**

```
public class GridDataDto
{
    public WellDto[] Wells { get; set; }

    public ZoneDto[] Zones { get; set; }

    public string[] Facies { get; set; }

    public CellDto MinLimits { get; set; }

    public CellDto MaxLimits { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ZoneDto[] Subzones { get; set; }

    public int MinK { get; set; }

    public int MaxK { get; set; }

    public string ColourCode { get; set; }
}

public class WellDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class CellDto
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int J { get; set; }
    public int K { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: maybe `Color.FromName` is what you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't have that option to pick from in the list after I do Color.

Comment: which `Color` class are you using? `System.Drawing.Color` or another?

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: Does this do the trick for you? => `var myColor = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colStr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Seems there is already a built in method for this `ColorConverter.ConvertFromString` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.convertfromstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's the old code anyway -

The `System.Windows.Media.Color` ToString() method returns a hex string of the aRGB values that looks like this: `#80C8DCF0` you can just split the bytes out and create a new color:

```
static Color FromString(string colorString)
{
    byte a = Convert.ToByte(colorString.Substring(1, 2), 16);
    byte r = Convert.ToByte(colorString.Substring(3, 2), 16);
    byte g = Convert.ToByte(colorString.Substring(5, 2), 16);
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(colorString.Substring(7, 2), 16);

    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks the ColorConverter.ConvertFromString was perfect

Answer (score 0):

I could be reading your question wrong but if you just want the legend to share the same colours as the "Sequence Stratigraphy" could you not just use the `ZoneColorizer`'s `Colorize` method on the `ZoneDto[]` object in your zone legend code's `Bind` method?